# Expand/Collapse UITableView always gets the wrong height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[As this video](https://youtube.com/shorts/M9B8TlAvwvI?feature=share), ([you can download source code from here](https://github.com/raxabizze/Demo), I've tried my best to remove all the unnecessary code)

I need to manually scroll through tableview to make it reset to the right height of each cell and if I expand and unexpand multiple cells, it will show the wrong height again.

I'm trying to use "systemLayoutSizeFittingSize" instead of "heightForRowAt". (CustomCell.swift)

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    
    let defaultHeight: CGFloat = 90
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: !isExpanded ? defaultHeight : tableView.contentSize.height + defaultHeight)
}
```

I want to use autolayout instead of giving the exact height for tableview. what do I do wrong?

Comment: As a general rule... "auto-sizing" table views can be problematic, as can be embedding table views in tableView cells. Lots of examples out there for expanding/collapsing table view rows/sections. I recommend you look at some other approaches. I forked your GitHub repo to show you one other way to go about this: https://github.com/DonMag/Demo

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can I take this as: I should avoid using multi-layer tableview?
Seems like one layer is okay.

Comment: As I said -- *as a general rule* ... table views are designed for auto-scrolling and memory management via cell reuse. When you throw away those benefits, you're fighting against the design and it's often a losing battle. Not to say there's ***never*** a valid reason to embed a table view in a table view cell, but as you see we can get the desired results by using the table view the way it's meant to be used... which is almost always the better approach.